# Azure AD B2C returns all the assigned roles

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jwt, saml, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm integrating the SSO flow with azure AD B2C using custom policies and SAML. When decoding the JWT token we are getting all the roles that user had previously also.I only need is the current role of the user. Can anyone have solution to achieve this?